# Is it possible to get scipy.integrate.odeint to work with a pair of vectors (or vector of vectors)

Tags: python, scipy, ipython, vectorization

## Using scipy.integrate.odeint For Free Fall Problems

#### Imports

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

%matplotlib inline
```

#### Constants and Integration Interval

```
G = 9.8    # m / sec / sec

# First 1 second of motion
t = np.arange (0, 1.1, 0.1)
```

#### Vector solution for velocity

Here we return a vector of acceleration in velocity_vector (), set the initial V0, and integrate for 1 second. We expect that Vx, and Vy are constant, and Vz is linearly decreasing with a slope of -G.

```
def velocity_vector (x, t, params):
    # x = (Vx, Vy, Vz)
    # Ordinary differential equation - velocity of an object in frictionless free-fall.
    g = params
    acceleration = np.array ([0, 0, -g])
    return acceleration

v0 = np.array ([1, 2, 0])
soln = odeint (velocity_vector, v0, t, args = (G,))

fig = plt.figure (1, figsize = (8,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax1.plot(t, soln [:,0])
ax1.set_xlabel ('time')
ax1.set_ylabel ('Vx')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax1.plot(t, soln [:,1])
ax1.set_xlabel ('time')
ax1.set_ylabel ('Vy')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax1.plot(t, soln [:,2])
ax1.set_xlabel ('time')
ax1.set_ylabel ('Vz')

plt.show ()
```

#### Vector solution for position and velocity in one dimension

Here we return a vector of acceleration and velocity in the z dimension in motion (), set the initial Z0 and V0, and integrate for 1 second. We expect that Xz is quadratic, and Vz is linearly decreasing with a slope of -G.

```
def motion (x, t, params):
    # x = (Sx, Vx)
    # Ordinary differential equation - velocity of an object in frictionless free-fall.
    g = params
    acceleration = np.array ([-g * t, -g])
    return acceleration

v0 = np.array ([5.0, 0])
soln = odeint (motion, v0, t, args = (G,))

fig,axes = plt.subplots(1, 2) # one row, two columns
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.6)

axes[0].plot(t, soln [:,0])
axes[0].set_xlabel ('time')
axes[0].set_ylabel ('Sz')

axes[1].plot(t, soln [:,1])
axes[1].set_xlabel ('time')
axes[1].set_ylabel ('Vz')

plt.show ()
```

#### Vector solution for position and velocity in one dimension

Let's see if we can combine the two approaches by supplying a list of vectors and returning a list of vectors.

```
def position_and_velocity (x, t, params):
    # x = (S, V) as vectors
    # Ordinary differential equation - velocity of an object in frictionless free-fall.
    g = params
    acceleration = np.array ([-g * t, -g])
    return acceleration

s = np.array ([0, 0, 5])
v = np.array ([1, 2, 0])
SV0 = np.array ([s, v])
soln = odeint (position_and_velocity, SV0, t, args = (G,))

#fig,axes = plt.subplots(1, 2) # one row, two columns
#fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.6)

#axes[0].plot(t, soln [:,0])
#axes[0].set_xlabel ('time')
#axes[0].set_ylabel ('Sz')

#axes[1].plot(t, soln [:,1])
#axes[1].set_xlabel ('time')
#axes[1].set_ylabel ('Vz')

#plt.show ()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-29-a12f336fc4fc> in <module>()
      9 v = np.array ([1, 2, 0])
     10 SV0 = np.array ([s, v])
---> 11 soln = odeint (position_and_velocity, SV0, t, args = (G,))
     12 
     13 #fig,axes = plt.subplots(1, 2) # one row, two columns


/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg)
    146     output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    147                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
--> 148                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
    149     if output[-1] < 0:
    150         print(_msgs[output[-1]])


ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

It seems that scipy.integrate.odeint () can deal with a vector and solve equations using vectors, but not a vector of vectors as in this example. Is there a way to avoid returning six different functions here, instead of just two?

Comment: If anyone knows how to add graphics, I have two .png files that I could try to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Warren mentioned, the answer is that odeint does require 1-D arrays. The trick is to set up the function passed to odeint so that it converts the 1-D array passed in as the second in the vector form desired - in this case, 2 3-D vectors, perform the calculations in vector form, then reshape the result back as a 1-D array.

The answer demonstrates the technique, using the convenient numpy reshape function.

```
def position_and_velocity (x, t, params):
    # x = (S, V) as vectors
    # Ordinary differential equation - velocity of an object in frictionless free-fall.
    G = params
    g = np.array ([0, 0, -G])
    # convert the 6 element vector to 2 3 element vectors of displacement and velocity
    # to use vector formulation of the math
    s,v = x.reshape (2,3)
    acceleration = np.array ([v * t, g])
    # reshape the two vector results back into one for odeint
    return np.reshape (acceleration, 6)

s = np.array ([0, 0, 5])
v = np.array ([40, 10, 0])
SV0 = np.array ([s, v])
# pass reshaped displacement and velocity vector to odeint
soln = odeint (position_and_velocity, np.reshape (SV0, 6), t, args = (G,))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`odeint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) handles only 1-d arrays.  To use `odeint` on your combined system, you'll have to concatenate your two 3-d vectors into a single 6-d vector.  If you are trying to use two existing functions that compute the two right-hand-sides of the equations for the two 3-d systems, you'll have to create a new function that accepts a 6-d vector, splits it into the appropriate 3-d subvectors, calls the two existing functions, and then concatenates the results as a 6-d vector to return.